# Unable to retrieve branch name during the RELEASE build using git-commit-id.branch of git-commit-id-plugin

Tags: git, build, maven-plugin

I am trying to retreive the branch name from the git repository. I am able to retreive the branch name when I build it in my local and in **Dev** environment. But when the build happens for the second time, where in the version changes from **SNAPSHOT** to **RELEASE**, the branch name is initialized with the pom **versions** of the project. Below is the plugin used

```
                  <plugin>
                        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>git-commit-id</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>revision</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <dateFormat>EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy</dateFormat>
                                    <prefix>git-commit-id</prefix>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

And below is the entry in the **properties** file where in the build details are loaded into, during build.

```
appsVersion=${pom.version}
appsBuildDateTime=${build-timestamp}
buildBranch=${git.branch}
```

Now the actual problem is, the **buildBranch** of the properties of file is being set with appsVersion. Thats is.,

```
     appsVersion=${pom.version}--->17.2.8
     buildBranch=${git.branch}--->is initialized with 17.2.8 instead of BRANCH NAME during 
RELEASE build.
```

I have also tried other plugins such as **Jgit(maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin)**, **org.codehaus.mojo(buildnumber-maven-plugin)** but in vain.

Please help me in figuring out what went wrong as we dont have an option to debug at runtime. Any help will be highly appreciated as I am totally stuck with this problem. And I dont want to try other plugins as I have spent considerable amount of time on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This could be similar to [`maven/git/GitDataProvider.java#determineBranchName()`](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/blob/7fcee779934329404b9ea5b0de236b3bdeb8e8d3/src/main/java/pl/project13/maven/git/GitDataProvider.java#L178-L191) or [`maven/git/GitDataProvider.java#determineBranchNameOnBuildServer()`](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/blob/7fcee779934329404b9ea5b0de236b3bdeb8e8d3/src/main/java/pl/project13/maven/git/GitDataProvider.java#L206-L210)

> If running within Jenkins/Hudson, honor the branch name passed via `GIT_BRANCH` env var.
>   This is necessary because Jenkins/Hudson always invoke build in a detached head state.

In your case, Jenkins might not be involved, but check the state of Git (git status) to see if the maven build operates on a branch or not (detached head, or tag)

Just in case, Check the value of the environment variable `GIT_BRANCH` or `GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH`, which should be used by this maven plugin.

---

As an alternative, [Anand Sunderraman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226906/anand-sunderraman) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094310/unable-to-retrieve-branch-name-during-the-release-build-using-git-commit-id-bran/44094758?noredirect=1#comment89866738_44094758) to have a look at [`ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin` issue 359](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/issues/359):

> I faced the same issue on VSTS build agents.
>   It turns out VSTS `git checkout` happens in detached mode based on last commit on particular branch, hence a commit-id in place of branch name.
>
> I implemented a workaround:

```
<configuration>
 <replacementProperties>
  <replacementProperty>
    <property>git.branch</property>
    <token>^.*$</token>
    <!--NOTE: required for VSTS env where checked out code is not on a branch-->
    <value>${env.BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH}</value>
    <regex>true</regex>
  </replacementProperty>
 </replacementProperties>
</configuration>
```

> Works locally as well if `env.BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH` is not available it fallback and use the `git branch`.

Comment: Hello VonC. I do not have the code for maven/git/GitDataProvider.java#determineBranchName() or maven/git/GitDataProvider.java#determineBranchNameOnBuildServer(). Even if i have it also I cannot debug it as I dont have the environment access on the QA environment to debug. Can you confirm whether I am using the right plugin and the right configuration.

Comment: @Hiren "I do not have the code" do you mean the link I provide in the answer are not working?

Comment: Hello VonC. I am a normal developer trying to get the branch name and display the same on a dahshboard. I have simply used **git-commit-id-plugin(pl.project13.maven)** to get the branch name. And even if I check the git code(which you have mentioned) I may not be able to debug it. Can you guide me through as what needs to be done?

Comment: And just a small correction. I have used **buildBranch=${git-commit-id.branch}** not **buildBranch=${git.branch}**

Comment: @Hiren Can you check `git status` when you are lunching your build? Are you in a detached HEAD mode? Are you launching your build with a `mvn:release prepare/perform`?

Comment: Hello Von. I am not sure whether the build team is launching "mvn:release prepare/perform" since we dont have the accesss to get this info. Even the deployment team dont have an idea I guess, as they just simply click on a button do do the build (as it is automated). But may be they might be doing the build for release. If you need info let me know Von, I will try to get it.

Comment: @Hiren sure: having more information about the build process would be nice. But also any version you can find: git version, Java version, maven version, ... and the OS (windows, Linux, Mac?)

Comment: Hello Von. Below are the verions details :
**jdk1.7.0_79, 
Maven_3.3.9, 
jenkin 2.32.2**
But couldnt able to figure out the git version (Checked the console logs in Jenkins page but in vain)
If git version is required, then just tell me which command to run and where to run. Thanks alot Von.

Comment: @Hiren "`git version`" should be enough to tell you the version of Git. You can make a dummy job with a single shell step executing that command.

Comment: Hello Von. we are using git 3.0.4 version and native client version 1.8.4.

Comment: Hello Von. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: @Hiren I don't have much more, except check the  environment variable GIT_BRANCH or GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH used in your Jenkins job (where the plugin pl.project13.maven was used)

Comment: Can you suggest anyother plugins which could be potentially suitable for my requirement? As I told you that have already tried other plugins such as Jgit(maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin), org.codehaus.mojo(buildnumber-maven-plugin).

Comment: @Hiren No I use  pl.project13.maven myself, without any issue.

Comment: @VonC what if my jenkins is not using the GIT plugin do you think I can work around that ?

Comment: @AnandSunderraman Not sure; beside implementing your own plugin, which would retrieve the information.

Comment: @VonC i found a solution at https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/issues/359 and it worked like a charm

Comment: @AnandSunderraman Good catch! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution to the above question could be in here

https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/issues/359

It worked like a charm for me